# What is the meaning of "saudade" and what good translations into other languages exist?

Tags: significado, tradução

It is often claimed that *saudade* cannot be translated into other languages. Is that so? If there are particularly direct or close translations, what are they?

Explanations of the etymology and history of use of *saudade* and its proposed translations are welcome.

Comment: On a side note, it's big myth to believe other cultures can't grasp the meaning of "saudade" just because they might not have a noun to name it.

Comment: @bfavaretto True.

Comment: There's no single-word translation for this; it seems to be unique to Latin languages.

Comment: This question is too broad: "into other languages" invites infinite answers - english, Spanish, German, Esperanto, Elfic, Klingon??

Comment: @ANeves Yes, if this question keep open the site will explode. Maybe not. What's the **real** problem? Even in SO we have infinite questions like this.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem dois problemas: 1. são duas perguntas numa; 2. não é concreta e tem demasiadas respostas esperadas - facilmente umas 50. `If your question (...) has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format ` - http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Se acham que este tipo de perguntas deve fazer parte do pt.SE, sugiro que abram essa discussão no [meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/search?q=broad). Se o fizerem, podem-me avisar por favor? Eu estaria interessado. :)

Comment: @ANeves You don't understand my question: What's the **real** problem? The problem you cited is not real.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can only repeat what I wrote before, in other words. @bigown, your question is not a good match for the StackExchange format; my opinion is backed by the FAQ, site tools, etc. I suggest you open a [meta question](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/) if you want to advocate inclusion of these types of questions in portuguese.SE .

Comment: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/55/23

Comment: You are advised to rephrase your question in order to avoid sounding like you want to aimlessly translate the word to several languages.

Comment: @E_net4 feel free to change. For me the question don't ask for this.

Comment: @bigown All I can do is suggest an edit. Since we seem to have an agreement by now, it made more sense that you modified the question yourself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Nostalgias e morriñas

It is [an oft-repeated myth that the Portuguese and Galician word *saudade* “cannot be translated”](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Palavra_.C3.BAnica_em_portugu.C3.AAs) into other languages. It certainly can! It just may take more than one word to do so adequately.

The basic sentiment is one that mixes together aspects of melancholy, loneliness, love, distance temporal or spatial, and permanent loss.  Even though few languages (but not quite none: see below) have just a single word encompassing all of those, it is no mean feat to **combine *multiple* words** to produce just the right *matiz*, no matter the language.

Because of the [difficulties in finding precisely the right shade of meaning](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade) in translating the Portuguese and Galician word *saudade* into Spanish, the Spanish have appropriated the word for themselves: [an entry for *saudade* can be found in the DRAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=saudade), where it lists as senses the words *soledad, nostalgia, añoranza*. The last of those three words, *añoranza*, is perhaps best translated into English as “missing”, “longing”, or especially “pining”.  *Saudade* has elements of all those and more, which is why the Spanish often enough just give up and use *saudade* directly. :)

Certainly *nostalgia* alone isn’t good enough, since *saudade* is the melancholy feeling of loneliness that comes from missing someone or something or some place or some bygone era, combined the critical connotation that that thing which is missed was quite dear to you yet now is gone forever and shall never return.

You need a word or phrase that mixes together all three of love and loss and distance.  *Nostalgia* alone cannot cover all that territory, nor can the English refrain *the dear departed*, which are people not feelings.

The exact etymology leading from some Latin word like *solitate* to modern *saudade* is disputed<sup>[1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Etimolog.C3.ADa), [2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Etimologia)</sup> but the presence of intermediate forms in literature like *soëdade, soidade* and *suidade* suggest a word in flux.  It is reasonably simple to hypothesize the lenition of the Latin *l* from a word of Latin origin (as occurred with the loss of *l* in the definite articles and dative pronouns derived from Latin *ille/illa/illum*), but again, there may be more factors involved (like associations with words like *suave*).

It is not even certain that *saudade* has its origin in Portugal; it may have originally come from Galicia, and is certainly associated with that land. [From Wikipedia](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade):

> Para Joaquim de Carvalho, a explicación desta localización non é allea á orixe céltica. Unamuno supón a orixe da saudade nas formas da paisaxe galega, "*un paisaje habitable, que seduce como un nido incubador de morriñas y saudades*". Na mesma liña, Gerald Brenan ve na saudade unha orixe indubidablemente climática: os ventos atlánticos proporciónanlle a Galicia o mesmo espírito lánguido que a Irlanda e ás Illas Hébridas. Isto atópase nos diálogos de Martín Codax co seu mar.

Although there are other languages with words that are more or less close to that of *saudade*, apparently the language with a word that is closest is Welsh, which [per Wikipedia’s article on the word](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Palavra_.C3.BAnica_em_portugu.C3.AAs) has *hiraeth*:

> Existe o mito de que a palavra 'saudade' só existe na língua portuguesa e como tal não pode ser traduzida correctamente. De fato, o sentimento de saudade não tem significação específica em outras línguas.
>
> [...]
>
> A palavra que mais se assemelha é "Hiraeth" do galês e é a única com uma conotação textualmente semelhante.

*Saudade* is not usually a level of sadness and anguish strong enough to quite qualify as actual depression.  However, there is a word which is.  [From Wikipedia again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Variations):

> *Saudade* is also associated with Galicia, where it is used similarly to the word *morriña* (longingness). Yet, *morriña* often implies a deeper stage of saudade, a "*saudade* so strong it can even kill," as the Galician saying goes. *Morriña* was a term often used by emigrant Galicians when talking about the Galician motherland they left behind. Although *saudade* is also a Galician word, the meaning of longing for something that might return is generally associated with *morriña*.

And from [the Galician Wikipedia page](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade):

> A frecuente identificación entre *saudade* e *morriña* nace da confusión de termos cercanos, pero o que caracteriza á morriña é a tristura depresiva, mentres que a saudade está caracterizada pola carencia de significación psicolóxica. A identificación da saudade coa *Sehnsucht* dos alemáns, proposta no seu día por José Luis Varela, afástaa da súa acepción de nostalxia dun ben perdido para considerala a procura dun obxecto descoñecido que se sente necesario. Celestino Fernández de la Vega, pola súa parte, identifica a saudade coa angustia como a entendía Heidegger, sen reparar en que a saudade carece da dimensión temporal da angustia.

Comment: I think you mean "no major feat," not "no mean feat," in your second paragraph. Your definitions of _saudade_ in your fifth paragraph is way too narrow. In most common use _saudade_ does not imply the thing or person you feel saudade for is gone forever.

Answer (score 15):

"Saudade" has its origin in the Latin language. Its root can be traced back to the meanings of isolation and loneliness (Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa, José Pedro Machado).

The current meaning of the word "saudade" is a feeling of missing someone, some place, or a past period in one's life. This feeling can be painful, and more or less strong.

Historically, it is linked to love relationships and, perhaps most importantly, with emigration. It is found often in poetry and in popular songs across the portuguese-speaking countries.

Possibly, the best **English** translation of "ter saudades" would be the verb "to miss", used in expressions such as:

- "I miss you" ("Tenho saudades tuas")
- "We miss those days" ("Sentimos saudades desses dias")
- "She misses her home" = "She is homesick" ("Ela está saudosa de sua casa", here "saudoso" is an adjective)

The [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saudade) suggests the word "wistfulness" for a direct translation of the noun "saudade". "Longing", and "yearning" are also related to the Portuguese meaning of "saudade".

I would suggest that the best translation in **Italian** is somewhat similar to the english translation, with the verb "mancare", for instance in "Mi manca casa mia".

Comment: *Saudade* is a noun, so saying that the best English translation for that noun is the verb *to miss* is shifting categories.  However, you could make your answer work better if the problem you were solving were restated as finding a translation for the verbal phrase *“ter saudade(s) de alguém ou de alguma coisa”*.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist. I edited that part and added a few possible noun translations.

Answer (score 3):

> The main goal of this answer is to complement other more objetive answers, summarizing articles that make parallels between the words. The list below [I extracted from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Similar_words_in_other_languages). It's important to keep in mind that there are cultural nuances that can slightly alter the meaning and context of each word, explained in the article above. Feel free to comment and suggest improvements.

## *Saudade* and approaches in other languages

- German: *sehnsucht*;
- Albanian: *mall*;
- Bosnian: *sevdah*;
- Spanish: *echar de menos* or *extrañar*;
- Romanian: *dor*;
- Welsh: *hiraeth*;
- Slovenian: *hrepeneti*, *koprneti*, *nostalgija*, *melanholija*;
- Finnish: *kaiho*;
- Korean: *keurium*;
- Mongolian: *betgerekh*;
- Japanese: *natsukashii*;
- Armenian: *karot*;
- Arabic: *wajd*;
- Turkish: *hüzün*;
- Indonesian: *galau*;
- Hebrew: *ergah*;
- Tamil: *pacalai*;
- Asturian: *señardá* or *señaldá*;
- Galician: *morriña*.

Comment: For the Spanish, you gave verbs not nouns.  [DRAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=saudade) offers *soledad, nostalgia, añoranza*, although those are not quite enough by themselves as I explain in my answer.  (But if you are listing verbs, you should probably add *añorar* itself.)

Comment: You could also add a line: “Galician: saudade”. :) Just kidding!! However, the difference between *saudade* and *morriña* there might be interesting.

Comment: @tchrist The complicated part of this answer is essentially limit the parallel in nouns only or extend to other words with different functions. About *morriña*, the article explains that there's a considerable distance of meanings between them, but I can edit this answer adding the galician word ;)

Comment: I agree that there’s considerable distance between *saudade* and *morriña* in that the latter can be fatal ([“Se teño unha morriña que me mata...”](http://ladherna-mirror.blogspot.com/2011/11/saudades.html)) but you don’t think of the former as being such. However, cognates of *nostalgia* and *melancholy* mentioned in the Slovenian entry might also be at some distance from *saudade* — I would say that the equivalent words in English, Portuguese, and Spanish aren’t quite the same as *saudade*, but I do not know Slovenian so perhaps it is different there. But you mentioned that. :)

Comment: Okay, lets improve the post. Added *morriña* as suggested ;)

Comment: ter saudades is not añorar, which means to grieve or to mourn